# How do I call an API when a website page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, api, dom, frontend

I need some help.
So, I want to call this API and display the file given by it on my website

this is the link:

https://ogramcloud.com/api/download/061b78fb83ee928748b78bc7ee9f3e98

It generates this:

```
{
  "download_link": "http://ogramcloud.com/static/files/Fly_Me_to_the_Moon_Evangelion_OST.mp3", 
  "file_key": "061b78fb83ee928748b78bc7ee9f3e98", 
  "message": "file restored successfully !", 
  "status": "success"
}
```

I need to call this and display the `http://ogramcloud.com/static/files/Fly_Me_to_the_Moon_Evangelion_OST.mp3` as a `<audio>` on my website.

how would I go to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution using js fetch api.

```js
var audioLink ;
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var audioSource = document.getElementById("audioSource");

fetch("https://ogramcloud.com/api/download/061b78fb83ee928748b78bc7ee9f3e98").then(response => response.json()).then(data => 
{
audioSource.src = data.download_link;
audio.load();
audio.play();
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```

Comment: Thank you!
can I do this for images of whatever file I may need?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do this .

Comment: Great ! I hope you wont mind upvoting the answer too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jQuery` to do that:

```
$(function () {
  $.get("https://ogramcloud.com/api/download/061b78fb83ee928748b78bc7ee9f3e98", function (response) {
    link = JSON.parse(response).download_link
    // append a <source> to your <audio> or do whatever you want with the link
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the fetch api or XMLHttpRequest, you can make a request to your api.

Add an `id` to the audio in the HTML.

```js
let audio = document.getElementById("audio");

fetch("https://ogramcloud.com/api/download/061b78fb83ee928748b78bc7ee9f3e98")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    audio.src = data.download_link;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
});
```

```html
<audio controls="controls" src="" id="audio">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.
</audio>
```